# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /auth/profile/ User has no profile. (user is creating but profile is not)

Tags: python, html, django, django-signals, django-profiles

I had created a custom registration form through which I am creating User and I want to create a profile of the user while creating a User. The code is working if I create a profile manually through admin but not creating while creating user. below is my code. please help me out.
**Models.py**

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from email.policy import default
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField( default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User_reg(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True,blank=False)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,unique=True)
    Userpassword = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class dr_reg(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image")
    specialisation = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    qualificaton =  models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=False,unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=False)
    state =  models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    dUsername = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,unique=True)
    dPassword = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    avatar = models.ImageField(default='#', upload_to='profile_images')
    bio = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bio

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)

        if img.height > 100 or img.width > 100:
            new_img = (100, 100)
            img.thumbnail(new_img)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)
```

**views.py**

```
def dr_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.POST.get('dfname')
        lname = request.POST.get('dlname')
        image = request.POST.get('img')
        qualification = request.POST.get('qualification')
        specialist = request.POST.get('specialisation')
        phone = request.POST.get('dphone')
        gender = request.POST.get('dsex')
        address = request.POST.get('dadd')
        state = request.POST.get('state')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        zip = request.POST.get('zip')
        email = request.POST.get('demail')
        dr_username = request.POST.get('duname')
        dr_password = request.POST.get('dpass')

        mydoctor = User.objects.create_user(dr_username, email, dr_password)
        mydoctor.first_name = fname
        mydoctor.last_name = lname
        mydoctor.is_doctor = True
        mydoctor.save()

        dr_reg.objects.create(fname=fname,lname=lname,image=image, qualificaton=qualification, specialisation = specialist, phone= phone, gender=gender, address=address, state=state, city=city, zip=zip, email=email, dUsername=dr_username, dPassword= dr_password,user=mydoctor)
        # dr_register.save()  
    
        messages.success(request, 'Registeration successful')
        return render(request, 'user/login.html')  

    else:
        return render(request, 'doctor/register.html')

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile is updated successfully')
            return redirect(to='users-profile')
    else:
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

        context = {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form
        }

        return render(request, 'user/edit-profile.html', context)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance).save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class LoginModuleConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'authenticate_me'

    def ready(self):
        import authenticate_me.signals
```

the last line `import authenticate_me.signals` is displaying in grey color.saying unused import and is not accessed.

Comment: Your signal sender is configured with `django.contrib.auth.models.User` but you defined your own user model. Try to use your own user model as the sender

Comment: Can you tell me the necessary code how can I perform this like how I can write my user model?

Answer (score 0):

if signals are not firing, it means you have not provided the correct `AppConfig` to django.

Pick one:

- hope into your `<app_name>/__init__.py` and add:

  `default_app_config = '<appname>.apps.<AppName>Config'`
- or, add `<appname>.apps.<AppName>Config` to `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `<appname>`

Comment: My appname is authenticate_me and I have add this 'authenticate_me.apps.LoginModuleConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @user:19235697 but its not working

Comment: try this: ```
    def ready(self):
        super().ready()
        from authenticate_me import signals  
```